# WebStorm. Запустить проект в браузере

Tags: javascript, html, webstorm

Проблема такая. Хочу поиграться с объектом истории через js, но браузер не разрешает это делать без доменного имени (same-origin policy), то есть тупо с проводника открыть файл нельзя.

Но продукты JetBrains дают классную возможность нажав кнопочку "показать в браузере" создаст что ли сервер с страницей и откроет его. Только вот кроме этой страницы там ничего нет.

То есть структура проекта:

```
- page.html
- scripts.js
```

Нажимаю page.html -> показать в браузере, все хорошо, но пробую открыть `script.js` получаю 404. Есть способ это решить? А то возможность удобная...

Comment: Вот [такая](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2016.1/using-jetbrains-chrome-extension.html) штука Вам не поможет ?

Comment: а каким образом Вы пытаетесь загрузить scripts.js в браузер? Джаваскрит просто так в браузере не откроешь, нужна html страничка. Или Вы просто пытаетесь открыть `http://localhost:63342/project-name/scripts.js`, прописав этот URL в адресной строке браузера?

Comment: Он подгружается в html файле. Но ничего не происходит, Поэтому я просто проверил его доступность через http://localhost:63342/project-name/scripts.js, на что мне браузер ответил 404